# How to flatten a subdocument into root level in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, if I have a document like this

```
{
  a: 1,
  subdoc: {
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  }
}
```

How can I convert it into a format like this? **(without using `project`)**

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

Comment: Why do you insist on doing it without `project`? Please answer this, because your reason might also exclude other possible answers.

Comment: @Philipp There're 30+ elements in the subdocument, so `project` means a lot of typing.

Comment: A good reason could be that the subdocument can change over time and, therefore, specifying 'b' and 'c' is not a good way if, later on, there would be a 'd' in there and you want all the subdocument to go into root.

Comment: As of MongoDB 3.4, there's an aggregation pipeline operator named [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/), that will allow you to make `subdoc` the new `$$ROOT`. But, it replaces root entirely. I don't know actually how to merge `subdoc` with fields already existing in the original root. Maybe this hints someone...

Comment: any alternative of $replaceRoot, in version 3.2....mongodb

Comment: still waiting for an elegant way to achieve this, even I hate projecting all of the fields

Answer (score 46):

**You can use [MongoDB projection i.e `$project` aggregation framework pipeline operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) as well.** (recommended way). If you don't want to use `project` check this [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-863)

> db.collection.aggregation([{$project{ . . }}]);

**Below is the example for your case:**

```
db.collectionName.aggregate
([
    { 
      $project: { 
        a: 1, 
        b: '$subdoc.b', 
        c: '$subdoc.c'
      } 
    }
]);
```

Gives you the output as you expected i.e.

```
    {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 2,
        "c" : 3
    }
```

Answer (score 38):

You can use **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** with a **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** stage as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { "subdoc.a": "$a" } },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$subdoc" }  }
])
```

Comment: If you have a lot of fields at root, you can use `mergeObjects` with special variable `$$ROOT` like:


`db.collection.aggregate([
    {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$subdoc"] } } },
    {$project: { subdoc: 0 } },
])`

Answer (score 26):

We can do this with [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) an alias for [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot) and the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator.

```
let pipeline = [
   {
      "$replaceWith": {
         "$mergeObjects": [ { "a": "$a" }, "$subdoc" ]
      }
   }
];
```

or

```
let pipeline = [
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
                "$mergeObjects": [{ "a": "$a" }, "$subdoc" ]
            }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `$$ROOT` in `$mergeObjects`

```
{ $replaceWith: {
        $mergeObjects: [ "$$ROOT", "$subdoc" ]
} }
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, the [`$replaceWith`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/#pipe._S_replaceWith) aggregation operator can be used to replace a document by another (in our case by a sub-document) as syntaxic sugar for the `$replaceRoot` mentioned by @chridam.

We can thus first include within the sub-document the root field to keep using the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) operator (also introduced in `Mongo 4.2` as an alias for `$addFields`) and then replace the whole document by the sub-document using `$replaceWith`:

```
// { a: 1, subdoc: { b: 2, c: 3 } }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { "subdoc.a": "$a" } },
  { $replaceWith: "$subdoc" }
])
// { b: 2, c: 3, a: 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query nested array element and display it at root level
You should use $unwind twice if you have 2 nested array

```
db.mortgageRequests.aggregate( [
       { $unwind: "$arrayLevel1s" },
       { $unwind: "$arrayLevel1s.arrayLevel2s" },
       { $match: { "arrayLevel1s.arrayLevel2s.documentid" : { $eq: "6034bceead4ed2ce3951f38e" } } },
       { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$arrayLevel1s.arrayLevel2s" } }
    ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is altering the result after it returns, using `map`.

```
collection.mapFunction = function(el) {
  el.b = el.subdoc.b;
  el.c = el.subdoc.c
  delete(el.subdoc);
  return el;
}

...

var result = await collection.aggregate(...).toArray();
result = result.map(collection.mapFunction);
```

Comment: I don't think you should do it this way.

Comment: Well, it's bad cause it runs on app memory and not on db level, but I don't have to rewrite every field of the database on $project clause

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the use of [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)

```js
db.collection.update({},{ $set: { "b": 2, "c": 3 }, $unset: { "subdoc": 1 } })
```

Of course if there are lots of documents in the collection, then much as above you need to loop the collection documents in order to get the values. MongoDB has no way of referring to a value of a field in an update operation alone:

```js
db.collection.find({ "subdoc": {"$exists": 1 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    var setDoc = {};
    for ( var k in doc.subdoc ) {
        setDoc[k] = doc.subdoc[k];
    }
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": setDoc, "$unset": "subdoc" }
    );
})
```

That also employs some safe usage of [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in order to make sure you are selecting documents where the "subdoc" key is actually there.

Comment: So there's no built-in operator/function in mongoDB to do this, right?

Comment: @svg The operators are what I mentioned. You cannot get the value of a field in an update alone, which is also what I said.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. I actually meant a single operator, in one shoot. Sorry I didn't say it very clearly.

Comment: BTW, creative use of `$set`&`$unset`. I'm afraid looping will be less performant than `$project`, right? If so, I'll stick to `$project`, but do more typing(There're 30+ elements in the subdocument).

Comment: @svg The two things are completely different. You are either manipulating the actual document or you are doing projection to re-shape a particular result, and which can only be done with aggregation. Decide which one you want to do. Alter your document or present results in a different way.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm just preparing data for analysis, it's not an issue for me whether or not to alter in-place. Thanks again.