# How to Flatten dynamic field with parent document - Spring data Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate, mongorepository

In my Spring boot project have a Document like so:

```
@Document(collection="AuditTable")
public class AuditTable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Map<String, String> properties;
```

where properties is a dynamic field i.e. it can take in as many different key-value pairs.

I use MongoRepository to store this value:

```
@Repository
public interface AuditTableRepo extends MongoRepository<AuditTable, String> {
}
```

Now when I store it in the Collection it looks like this:

[image]

whereas I want it to look like this:

```
"_id": "XYZ" 
"_class": "XYZ" 
"workCaseId":"12" 
"taskName":"AUDIT" 
"owner":"ANSHU" 
"createdDate":"XYZ"
```

Any idea about how I can fix this without using converters? Or if I do have to use them how should I do it?

I'm new to spring data mongodb as we have recently made the jump to mongo from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest mongo version then you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) (reference from [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903849/how-to-flatten-a-subdocument-into-root-level-in-mongodb/46705943#46705943))

```
let pipeline = [
    {
        "$replaceRoot":{
            "newRoot":{
                "$mergeObjects":[
                    {
                        "id":"$id"
                    },
                    "$properties"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```